# Profile Image Store Database or Server System

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to know what is your opinion on where to store the users profile pictures..

I am thinking to store it either in the database as a BLOB type OR in the system in a folder..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The usual way is to store them in a folder an put in the database just the location.

Answer (score 1):

Requests after these pictures are going to be very frequent that can slow down database functioning considerably. So, it is better to store those as files on server.
If you have small pictures about 10kB and 10000 users? just this table is going to weight 10 MB

Answer (score 1):

Considering modern browsers cache images and other assets, serving the file from the filesystem is preferred way as the database method will continue to retrieve the same amount of data regardless of it being already cached.

It will also cause a performance hit on your database once it starts handling lots of queries.